# How to modify Umbraco v9 CMS generated files

Tags: umbraco

I'm wondering if it is possible to make changes to the Umbraco CMS files.
For example the "umbraco.controllers.min.js" file.
These files get generated on build, so any changes I make get overwritten.
I'm trying to make a small change to the backend UI, but I can't see where the files are even being generated from.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is: I wouldn't change anything in Umbraco files. It may be possible for you to create your own plugin (as part of your website, outside of the files Umbraco controls/generates) and override whatever it is you want changed (depends on what it is specifically), but Umbracos own files should be off limits. Otherwise you will run into problems when upgrading and such.

Edit: although... Those files shouldn't regenerate on build, I think, if you've installed Umbraco via Nuget and all that. Are you changing files directly in the Umbraco source repository?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Specifically I am looking to make an amend to nested content item names in the backend UI. The following is found within umbraco.controllers.min.js...
`<span class="umb-nested-content__item-name" ng-class="{\'--has-icon\': vm.showIcons}" ng-bind="vm.getName($index)"></span>`
It would be great if I could add a .replace() on the ng-bind value to get rid of some unexpected square bracket characters that are appearing.
I will look into creating my own plugin, but I'm not sure why my files are regenerating. It was installed using .net cli. Yes in the source repo.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see your reply before now! I believe the brackets you are seeing could have something to do with missing translations? If not, I'd advise you to create an issue over on https://github.com/umbraco/umbraco-cms/issues (after you've checked it doesn't already exist) - it doesn't sound right that brackets are showing up for no reason. If it turns out to be a bug then you might get to fix it in Core, so it helps everyone!

Comment: And BTW, if you don't want to do the whole OSS contribution thing, the umbraco.controllers.js file is being compiled here: https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/5bfab13dc5a268714aad2426a2b68ab5561a6407/src/Umbraco.Web.UI.Client/gulp/config.js#L49 referring to controllers inside https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/tree/v9/contrib/src/Umbraco.Web.UI.Client/src/views - so I guess you'd have to find the code inside https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/tree/v9/contrib/src/Umbraco.Web.UI.Client/src/views/propertyeditors/nestedcontent somewhere ;-)